# Pullback of line bundle of negative degree has no global sections.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ with $k$-algebraically closed. Is it true that, for any $d >0$,  the pullback of any $\mathcal{O}(-d)$ under the inclusion $i:X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ satisfies $H^0(X, \, i^{*}\mathcal{O}(-d))=0$?

I am working with $X$ a smooth connected curve which is a complete intersection but I think this should be hold in more generality. Should I go the definition via sheafification of the pullback of is there a slick trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is a closed subscheme, the hyperplane class $H$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ restricts to an ample class $H_X$ on $X$. Then $i^* \mathcal{O}(-d) = -d H_X$, which cannot be effective for $d >0$.

Comment: I am sorry but I was looking for something more elementary. I just know some general scheme theory.

Comment: This *is* completely elementary: if something is ample, a positive multiple of it is effective, so no negative multiple can be effective.

Comment: Yes, I suspect so. But my course in algebraic geometry is stil in a phase where we are just developing general theory. I was wondering if there was some cohomological argument or some argument just involving basic properties of the pullback.

Comment: @Abellan: this is much more basic than any cohomological argument.

Comment: First, this is false for schemes in general. This is true in general only when $X$ is irreducible (as a scheme, which means also reduced) and positive dimensional.

Comment: I agree that $\dim X >0$ is necessary, but I do not think that irreducibility is needed. In fact the pullback of $\mathcal{O}(-d)$ is anti-ample on each component of $X$, so the same argument applies. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are. You can thicken, say a line in 3-space so that the thickened scheme $X$ has $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(-d))\neq 0$.

Comment: I mean, *reduced* is enough, you do not really need *irreducible*.

Comment: Sure, you can embed the sheaf of functions into the correct irreducible components, so you may always assume to start with the scheme is irreducible (assuming that all components are positive dimensional.

Comment: @Mohan: could you please explain the statement about your line bundle on a thickened line  having global sections?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Take a line $L$ in 3-space with the ideal sheaf $I$. Then you have an exact sequence, $0\to I/I^2\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}/I^2\to\mathcal{O}_L\to 0$. Since $I/I^2=\mathcal{O}_L(-1)^2$, take a surjection $I/I^2\to \mathcal{O}_L(d)$ for $d\geq -1$. Then the pushout gives a scheme $X$ with an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_L(d)\to \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_L\to 0$. Now, it is clear that $H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(-d))\neq 0$.